# auto.arima with xreg does not work within do.call

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, do.call

I am using `auto.arima` with `xreg` and `do.call`. I have realized that for some time series it works well, but for some others it produces the following error which I couldn't solve:

*Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent*

Here is a reproducible case:

```
# packages needed
require(magrittr)
require(forecast) # version 8.5

# create argument list
args=list()
args$y<-ts(c(100:140,rep(200,4),380,250),start=c(2016,1),frequency = 52)
args$seasonal<-F
args$xreg<-(diag(length(args$y))%>%.[,-c(1:24)])

# this works well
fit1<-auto.arima(y=args$y,seasonal=args$seasonal,xreg=args$xreg)

# but this does NOT work, although everything is the same!
fit2<-do.call(auto.arima,args)

# however, if we change arguments slightly, do.call works well, as seen below:
args$y<-ts(10:20,start=c(2016,1),frequency = 52)
args$xreg<-(diag(length(args$y))%>%.[,-c(1:4)])

fit2<-do.call(auto.arima,args)
```

I don't know where the problem is, auto.arima or do.call function.

Edit: I use auto.arima within a function which takes auto.arima arguments as `...`. In other words, I don't know exactly which arguments will be supplied beforehand. A working answer should work for the following code:

```
foo<-function(vec_ts,...){

  args = list(...)
  args$y<-vec_ts # time series vector

  fit<-do.call(auto.arima,args)

}
```

`...` may or may not include xreg. Without xreg, the function above works like a charm. But when `...` includes xreg matrix, it *sometimes* doesn't work (not always).

Comment: try `fit2<-do.call("auto.arima", args)`

Comment: @Istrel no help, still not working. 
actually, `do.call(auto.arima,args)` works very well in most cases. so I don't think that quote has to do anything here/